# Is " just as good of a" a sufficiently legitimate expression to be used in academical writing?

Tags: usage, expressions

Say, "sin(x) is  just as good of a smooth function as exp(x)"

Comment: What about: Sin(x) has the same degree of smoothness as exp(x) ?

Comment: Yes, it can be reformulated in many ways, but it is just an example.

Comment: It's a legitimate expression, but it's very informal.  I would not use it in academic writing.

Comment: @Serguei I checked "**as good of a smooth function as**" on google books. There is no book which has used this phrase. I think Its not a good option.

Comment: The *of* is a colloquial interpolation which should be omitted in academic writing. *Good* is rather vague--does it mean "effective" or "reliable" or "valid" or what?

Comment: @StoneyB I think, **Good** describes the smoothness ! It has a good smoothness- We can take derivatives infinitely, e.g., => sin(x) => cos(x) => - sin(x) => -cos(x) => sin(x), ..., similarly exp(x) => exp(x) => exp(x) => exp(x) ...

Comment: Yes, but what makes a function's smoothness "good"? How does a good smooth function differ from a bad smooth function or a mediocre smooth function?

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I feel stupid, sorry. The more derivative you can take, the more smoothness you can achieve. The more smoothness you have, the easier calculation you will face. I hope I was successful to convey my thoughts correctly

Comment: Well, if the important thing is that the two functions are equally smooth, that's what you should say: *sin(x) is just as smooth a function as exp(x)*, or *sin(x) has the same smoothness as exp(x)*. "Good" has very little meaning--for all we can tell, the two are just as good because their names have the same number of letters!

Comment: Personally, I would use the technical term **degree of smoothness** since it has an accurate definition. However, It seems that the OP has some reasons to avoid using it

Comment: OK. Probably, I should offer a more clear example, Suppose, I want to find a trajectory of a bullet.   Then I may argue that the calculations based on the assumption that the bullet is a ball are every bit as accurate as those made in assumption that  it is a cone. And I would like to say: "The ball approximation is just as good of a model as the cone one"

Comment: But there you've given us a measure of "goodness". Why would you say that that the ball approximation is just as "good" a model [note: no **of**] when what you mean is that it's just as **accurate** a model? In any technical discourse you want to express yourself as precisely as the discipline allows, not just sort of wave your hand in the general direction of what you mean.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, your "just as good a model" solves my problem. I must think it over

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> just as good as

has the meaning that two *somethings* can be used interchangeably. It is an informal expression.  Generally there is no "good" or "bad" value judgements in mathemetical academic writing.

"Sufficiency" is the important condition for mathematical academic writing, especially in proofs when several criteria may be necessary to address.  Often, the criteria for sufficiency is stated.

A way to express this in academic-ese might be

> sufficiently similar

The statement

> Coke is just as good as Pepsi for quenching your thirst on a hot day.

means they are "enough alike" to be used.

A possible academic way of expressing this might be

> Coke and Pepsi are sufficiently similar for quenching your thirst on a hot day.
>
> The smoothness of the sin(x) and exp(x) curves are sufficiently similar that they may be used interchangeably without loss of generality.